# Lose my objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have `UITableView` with `UISearchController` filled with my custom objects. When i find some objects i call `reloadData` method. But i can't see any objects, because they are lost all the time. I have groups, which translate into sections, each group contain objects, which translate into rows of section.

There are some code and logs:

`UISearchControllerDelegate` method implementation:

```
- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController
{
    // Searching

    // Put all found objects into findedObjects
    // Sort findedObjects to groups and put them into findedGroups

    findedObjects = searchResults;

    [findedGroups removeAllObjects];

    for (InfoGroup *buffGroup in groups)
    {
        InfoGroup *newGroup = [InfoGroup groupWithName:buffGroup.groupName andObjects:nil isMainGroup:buffGroup.mainGroup];
        newGroup.groupImageName = buffGroup.groupImageName;
        newGroup.groupPeoples = buffGroup.groupPeoples;

        BOOL flag = NO;

        for (InfoObject *obj in findedObjects) //sort objects
        {
            if ([obj.objectGroup.groupName isEqualToString:newGroup.groupName])
            {
                [newGroup.groupObjects addObject:obj];
//                obj.objectGroup = newGroup;
                NSLog(@"count of groupObjects: %li",[newGroup.groupObjects count]);
                flag = YES;
            }
        }

        if (flag) // if new group have more than 0 objects, put her in array
        {
            [findedGroups addObject:newGroup];
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"found %li groups and summary %li objects", [findedGroups count],[findedObjects count]);

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

`UITableView` data source methods

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSInteger count = ([findedGroups count] > 0) ? [findedGroups count] : [groups count];

    NSLog(@"number of sections: %li", count);

    return count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSInteger count = ([findedGroups count] > 0) ? [[findedGroups[section] groupObjects] count] : [[groups[section] groupObjects] count];

    NSLog(@"number of rows: %li in section: %li", count, section);

    return count;
}
```

There are very interesting logs (while typing something in search field, cleaned):

```
found 2 groups and summary 5 objects <----- 5 objects
number of sections: 2 <----- HERE TWO
number of rows: 0 in section: 1 <----- here 0 objects
number of rows: 0 in section: 0 <----- here 0 too

found 1 groups and summary 1 objects
number of sections: 1
number of rows: 0 in section: 0

found 1 groups and summary 1 objects
number of sections: 1
number of rows: 0 in section: 0
```

So, i lose my objects somewhere between `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `numberOfRowsInSection`.

Any suggestions? May be i missing something, but i can't find what.

Sorry for anxiety. Really stupid mistake waste hours of time.

Comment: You'll need to show what's in the arrays (i.e. what types) and how they are populated.

Comment: Look at updated post @trojanfoe

Answer (score 0):

**Just for mark post as solved**

I solve the problem. Because i put nil here

```
InfoGroup *newGroup = [InfoGroup groupWithName:buffGroup.groupName andObjects:nil isMainGroup:buffGroup.mainGroup];
groupObjects array was not initialized.
```

So i'm just update method for that case:

```
+(instancetype)groupWithName:(NSString*)initialName andObjects:(NSMutableArray*)initialObjects isMainGroup:(BOOL)initialMain
{
    if (initialObjects)
    {
        [ig setGroupObjects:initialObjects];
    } else
    {
        ig.groupObjects = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
}
```